# Error executing library in Rserve from Java

Tags: java, r, rjava, rserve

When I start [Rserve](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rserve/index.html) from [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) and try to connect to Rserve using RSclient as in the code below:

```
#Loading Libraries
library(Rserve)
library(RSclient)

#Loading Rserve
Rserve(args='--no-save --slave')

#Open Connection to Rserve and Executing openNPL
conn <- RS.connect(port=6311)
RS.eval(conn,library(openNLP))
```

All works ok.

But if I try to start Rserve from command line (simulating what Java does). As the code:

```
#loading Rserve from command line, to simulate what java does.
#Using Mac OS 10.10.2
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --no-save --slave --RS-port 6311

#in RStudio
#Loading Rclient
library(RSclient)

#Loading Rserve
Rserve(args='--no-save --slave')

#Open Connection to Rserve and Executing openNPL
conn <- RS.connect(port=6311)
RS.eval(conn,library(openNLP))
```

I get this error in RStudio:

```
rsc_abort: connection closed by peer
Error in RS.eval(conn, library(openNLP)) : 
  read error - could not obtain response header
```

And this error in the command line:

```
  Invalid memory access of location 0x110 rip=0x7fff8ea0d5d2
```

[Here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rosuda.devel/1546) and [here](http://forums.ohdsi.org/t/unable-to-load-sqlrender-library-from-java-rserve-client/313) are similar problems reference. My original problem is with [RJDBC](https://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/), not with [openNLP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/index.html), and it seems that both has [rJava](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) in common. I used openNLP here because it's easy to simulate, with no need to database connection. Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: I had the same error and it was most likely related to lack of memory on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set exactly the same parameters for your R CMD. Make sure to check whether RStudio uses exactly the same Java version.

As for memory settings, you can always use this trick

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx=2G"
```

to set memory size available to JVM. Using `_JAVA_OPTIONS` you can enforce settings that will be used by JVM.